# How do you display data when you have multiple machine learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, artificial-intelligence

I have developed a program that finds the probabilities of around 500 classes based on some training data that involves a few thousand features.

It works by training about 500 logistic regression models that take these few thousand features and find the probability of a single class. Each model finds the probability for a different class, so I am able to find to find the probability for each of the classes.

Since these are all different models, I have been able to find the accuracy for each model and have the mean accuracy by averaging all of these values.

My problem is that right now I have these 500 or so data points and the average and I don't really know how to represent them graphically. I can't really plot them with a line graph since there isn't much relation between the classes and the ROC curves don't work since this isn't a binary classification.

Does anyone have any suggestions on ways I can graph this data? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you have 500 classes which each have been assigned 500 probabilities?  Does the mean accuracy refer to the mean accuracy for a particular class ( i.e. there are 500 different mean accuracies ) or is the mean accuracy refer to the accuracy of the probability assigned to each class?

Suggestion:  Assign an arbitrary unique index of 1 to 500 to each class.  Plot the class index against the class probability, with a vertical error bar

[image]

Comment: The mean accuracy was for each class and I have a total average accuracy across all the classes as well. The graph is exactly what I want, thank you so much!